# Вывод всех записей из базы данных

Tags: while, php, mysql

```
$a = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`"));
print_r($a);
```

Как сделать, чтобы print_r($a) возвращал ВСЕ записи из базы данных без использования цикла while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Не используйте модуль mysql.**

В mysqli есть замечательная функция под названием [fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Или в PDO есть функция [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Думаю это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Нужно именно в MySQL

Comment: не знаю как сейчас, но спустя 2-3 месяца после выхода php5.3 fetch_all() в mysqli глючила, пришлось отказаться

Comment: @SnikersSurgut, может вы опишите свою проблему? Что/кто вам не дает использовать цикл. 

К тому же функции fetch_all и fetchAll по скорости работают точно так же как если бы Вы использовали цикл. И вообще зачем нужно именно mysql? Функции mysqli и pdo работают с БД MySQL.